# Using TSX files with electron-compile error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm trying to compile my electron program using electron-compile-prebuilt. React and typescript are supposed to be supported out of the box, however it throws a console error from the React markup tags `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`,

Is there a compiler option that needs to be used to support React syntax in TSX? When converted to JSX it works okay.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `.compilerc` at the root of your project and that you have defined your TypeScript compiler options for the `text/typescript` MIME type. Your TypeScript compiler options must include the `"jsx": "react"` option.

Here's my `.compilerc`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": ["es2016-node5", "react"],
        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      },
      "text/typescript":{
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap":true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": ["es2016-node5", "react"],
        "sourceMaps": "none"
      },
      "text/typescript":{
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap":false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For me adding the text/typescript resolved the syntax error. However I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined`. js and jsx works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: The `document` object doesn't exist in the main process. Are you using `document` in the main process or the render process?